# Dented Corny Keg

Tags: kegging

I ordered some new corny kegs and a couple of them arrived with a dent in their side. I was wondering (hoping) if anyone knew of a method of removing those dents.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the dent doesn't effect the keg volume significantly I would leave it be.

If you're familiar with how to repassify stainless you can try to hammer it out with an auto body palm hammer.

Unless it was an "as is" purchase I would return them.

Comment: Last sentence is IMO most important point. If you order some hardware, you shouldn't need to fix it right away!

Comment: Thanks for the info! I was planning on returning them unless there was an easy fix that I didn't know about.